# How to split Windows boot partition and system partition to seperate drives

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd, bios, nvme

I recently purchased an M.2 NVMe SSD for my PC and adapted it to PCI since I do not have an M.2 slot on my Motherboard (GA-Z68AP-D3, if that helps). I plan to run Windows off of it, but it seems that I'm not able to boot from it.

A solution that was suggested in an other thread quite some time ago was to have the boot partition and the system partition split across multiple drives. That would mean that I'd just have the files to boot on my HDD but otherwise windows would, when launched, run on the SSD.
Is that at all possible, and if so, how would I go about doing it?
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: you probable did, but just to make sure, did you enable in the BIOS to boot from NVMe / PCIe??

Comment: @Albin Yea, I enabled whatever seemed neccessary, however, given the age of the Motherboard, not much was available then. Nevertheless I do see the SSD in the Windows install menu, but if I install windows on it it's of no use.

Comment: Seeing the SSD in the windows install menu and being able to boot from it are two different things, you NEED to enable booting from MVMe/PCIe in the BIOS is it there at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems with a few updates (eg [here](https://forums.tweaktown.com/gigabyte/56453-gigabyte-ga-z68ap-d3-rev-1-uefi-bios-help.html) or [here](https://drivers.softpedia.com/get/BIOS/Gigabyte/Gigabyte-GA-Z68AP-D3-rev20-BIOS-Ua5-UEFI-BIOS.shtml)) for your board you can install UEFI instead of BIOS (if it's not included in you're revision yet). If you get UEFI working you could try to enable the boot options by "updating" the UEFI [as it is described here](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/592133-howto-get-nvme-support-on-older-motherboards/). But be careful you have to know what you are doing, there is a chance to make you're system unusable!

Comment: Thank you for checking that out and especially for the headsup. I will look into these options and try not to brick my board ;)

Comment: @anaAdo Let us know if you have any problems, if the answer helped you to solve the question please consider to "accept" it.